# Managing memory with NSString objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Here is what i have in my main method:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {  
    NSString *string=[[NSString alloc]init];  
    NSLog(@"%@   The retain count is:%d", string, [string retainCount]);  
    NSLog(@"Hello, World!");  
    return 0;  
}
```

The output on executing this piece of code is "The retain count is :-1".
I was expecting it to give me 1 as the retain count, since i created the object using alloc.
I have similar problems when i try to retain or release the NSString objects.

When i try with NSArray, i get the retain count immediately after creation of object as 2. I do not understand the mechanism of how the objects are being treated.
Please explain!
Thanks in advance..

Comment: don't ever look at the retain count. It's almost never useful and it only causes confusion. @DarkDust has a great answer as to how you should manage your memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

-1 is what you get if you cast `UINT_MAX` to a signed value. `UINT_MAX` is the documented retain count of objects which are never released, which includes string literal objects.

Speaking of [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount), I suggest reading the big box about how retainCount is generally not useful.

Comment: @Sahitya Tarumani: Everything that you allocate, you must deallocate. In Cocoa, you don't do this directly; instead, you release, and when everything that owned an object has released it, it deallocates itself. An object that was never allocated, such as a  literal string, does not need to be deallocated; since ensuring that deallocation happens only at the proper time is the only reason for reference counting, an object that won't deallocate itself need not count retains. Such objects return `UINT_MAX` as their retain count. These are what I called “permanent objects” in my other comment.

Comment: "An object that was never allocated, such as a literal string"...I did use the statement {...NSString *string=[[NSString alloc]init];...}...Doesnt this statement allocate memory to string?

Comment: Oops! Wasn’t paying enough attention. `[[NSString alloc] init]` isn’t a string literal, but it gives you a *singleton*, the empty string object, which is permanent. (It doesn’t need to create a new object each time, since NSStrings are immutable.)

Comment: @Sahitya Tarumani: It doesn't in the current implementation, as Ahruman says, which is how you can get away with not following the rules. However, it may, so you should follow the rules anyway.

Comment: @Ahruman...Is this true for NSMutableString class objects too?

Comment: No, because mutable strings are mutable. If you call `[[NSString alloc] init]` twice, the resulting objects are guaranteed to be equal forever, which is why it’s a valid optimization. For mutable strings, you need to be able to change one without affecting the other.

Comment: Wow!! Now the things seem to be in place...I am able to grab these concepts...I guess i can carry on from here on...Thanks a tonnnne for ur answers..i am relatively new to cocoa so trying to find my way out of confusions! Big thanks to u again!

Comment: Ah! One more doubt..This is with NSArray..are the NSArray objects permanent too? i ask this because when i do {..NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc]init]..}, i get the retain count as 2...again not wat i expected....not even 2^31-1....Why is that so?

Comment: @Sahitya Tarumani: It doesn't matter. Don't worry about whether an object is permanent or not. It is trivia, not anything that should affect how you write your code. It is also subject to change at any time. Simply follow the rules described in the documentation at all times.

Answer (score 14):

You shouldn't focus on the raw retain count value, as this can be a different value depending on various things. For example, in your first line you are allocating what is the equivalent of `@""`, that is an empty string. This is optimized by an object that cannot be deallocated and is shared wherever you're "allocating" it. The same is true for all static strings, e.g. look the value returned by `[@"Hello" retainCount]`.

Instead you should focus on *relative* retain count. That is, is the retain count increased (`+1`), does it stay the same (`+0`) or is it decreased (`-1`). You always need to make sure that these relative value sum up to 0.

An example:

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
[foo retain];
[foo release];
[foo autorelease];
```

The `alloc` method returns an object with `+1`, and `retain` also increses the count by 1. So by the end of line 2, we're at `+2`. Both `release` and `autorelease` have the effect of `-1`, so at the end of line 4 you're at `+0` and everything is fine.

There are a few simple rules: if the method name is `alloc`, starts with the words `copy` or `create` then you will get an object with retain count `+1`. All other methods (especially those start with `get`) should return objects with retain count `+0`. If your method needs to create an object but its name implies that a `+0` object should be returned, you can do this:

```
- (Foo *) bar {
    Foo *result = [[Foo alloc] init]; // +1
    return [result autorelease]; // -1
    // Object lives until the autorelease pool is drained,
    // but relative retain count is +0.
}
```

Comment: int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {     

NSString *string=[[NSString alloc]init];    
NSLog(@"%@   The retain count is:%d", string, [string retainCount]);    
NSLog(@"Hello, World!");    
return 0;  

}

Comment: This is why you shouldn't really even look at relative retain count.  Autorelease does not affect the retain count.  What it does is transfer ownership to the autorelease pool.

Comment: `create` does not mean “returns an owning reference” in Cocoa-land. It means that in CF-land; in Cocoa, the word is `new`. (Remember the acronym NARC: New, Alloc, Retain, or Copy.) Also, the obligatory link: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Comment: @JeremyP: You are correct about transfering ownership, but if you send `autorelease` to an object *x* times the pool will later call `release` on the object *x* times. And in order to keep you memory clean you *do* need to care about the relative retain count, or how else do you ensure that objects get cleaned up at the right time (and do get cleaned up) ?

Comment: @Peter Hosey: You're right, thanks for the clarification and obligatory link :-)

Comment: @DarkDust: The issue is with the idea that you can measure how the retain count has changed to measure the effect you've had on how doomed the object is. You can't. To borrow your example, at the end of line 4, the object's `retainCount` is 1, not 0; its net change (so far) is +1, not +0. It will become 0/+0 only when the autorelease pool is drained, sometime later. Worrying about retain counts *at all* is a path to madness; it is far better to exclusively consider ownership.

Comment: @DarkDust: No you don't care about the retain count i.e. you do not care about the specific number returned by `retainCount`.  You do care that each retain is balanced by a release or autorelease.

Comment: Really sorry for responding so late..    @DarkDust..sorry abt the confusing comment too :(.....After reading the answers and the comments, i understand that the retain counts are misleading me...i understand the concepts in memory management and ownership, its just that i do not seem to follow them when it comes to classes under NSObject like NSString or NSArray....I wanted an explanation for that..

Comment: @Sahitya Tarumani: You do need to follow them. A permanent object—one that does not implement reference-counting, such as string literals—lets you get away with not following the rules, because there's no leak for not releasing it and no crash for over-releasing it (both because a permanent object does not die no matter what you do), but it is still good practice to follow the memory management anyway, unconditionally. The example you showed does violate the rules, so you should fix that.

Comment: @JeremyP: That is exactly what my post is about: don't care about the absolute value, care about the relative value. That's what you mean with keeping the balance: thinking in relative values merely is a tool to keep that balance.

Comment: @DarkDust: No, the point is that the retain count is an implementation detail.  You need to think in terms of the abstract concept of **ownership** which is not explicitly stored anywhere. An autorelease, for instance balances a retain even though the retain increases the retain count by 1 and the autorelease has no effect on the retain count (either relatively or absolutely).